# Tag friends by facebook ID using Open Graph in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

What kind of elements does the `NSArray * tags` of `FBOpenGraphAction` expect? From the [Open Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) tool it seems like it just wants some facebook IDs as fodder. However when doing that

```
id<OpenGraphObject> event = (id<OpenGraphObject>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
event.url = @"http://example.com/obj1234?fb:app_id=1111&og:type=myapp:share";
id<OpenGraphShareAction> action = (id<OpenGraphShareAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
action.object = event
action.tags = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3300252], [NSNumber numberWithInt:585025503], nil];
```

and then posting with

```
[FBRequestConnection
    startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/myapp:share"
    graphObject:action
    completionHandler: ...
 ];
```

However this will not work - `[__NSCFNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't expect an NSNumber, but an NSString. This would make perfect sense, given we're talking about IDs.

Try it out and let us know how it goes